# Proof or counter these gcd arguments:

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

(a) For all positive integers $n$, we have gcd$(2n−1, n) = 1$.

For this, first I tried the Euclidean Algorithm. I divided $2n-1$ by $n$, and got $n-(1/n)$. Then, I didn't know what to do with $1/n$.

I also tried expressing them by a multiple. Say the gcd of them is $d$, so $2n-1=dk$ and $n=dl$ for natural numbers $k,l$. I eventually arrived at $d(2l-k)=1$, and didn't know what to do.

(b) For all positive integers $n$, we have gcd$(4n−2, n) = 2$.

*(b) is solved.

Comment: *Hint:* Suppose $d$ is simultaneously a divisor of $2n-1$ as well as $n$.  Then this means that $2n-1=kd$ for some integer $k$ as well as.....

Comment: Please show what progress you have made towards an answer, so people will know what level of response will be helpful.

Comment: @Joffan sorry, I've added details in my edit

Comment: You arrived at $d(2l-k)=1$ and so $d$ is a divisor of $1$.  What are the possible divisors of $1$?  What does that mean $d$ is equal to?  What does that mean $\gcd(2n-1,n)$ is equal to?

Comment: @JMoravitz We know $d(2l-k)=1$, so $2l-k=1/d$. We know $l, k, d$ are natural numbers so $d$ must be 1. Correct?

Comment: It is essentially correct, however since we are talking about integers specifically, this proof and question should have been assigned *before* we have formally gotten to division and rational numbers.  Your argument should completely avoid division wherever possible.  Instead of using division, use *divisibility* which is a related but fundamentally different concept.  Instead of dividing both sides by $d$, we can say directly that $d$ is a divisor of $1$.  Since the only divisor of $1$ is $1$ itself, we reach our desired conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) is wrong, take $n=3$ then we get $$\gcd(10;3)=1$$

Comment: Why not just $n=1$?  (i.e. OP did absolutely no work to test the hypothesis)

Comment: this better, and simplier, but i like the number $3$

Comment: It is a great number :).

Comment: a prime number and a Erdos number

Comment: My favorite use of $3$ has to be its position in front of *all* other naturals in the total ordering established by [Sharkovskii’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharkovskii%27s_theorem).

Comment: this is nive to know

Answer (score 0):

For non-zero integers $a,b$ and integer $c$ we have $$\gcd (a,b)=\gcd (a-bc,b).$$ Proof: For integer $d\ne 0$ we have

(i). If $d|a$ and $d|b$ then $d|(a-bc)$. Because $a/d,b/d\in \Bbb Z$ so $(a-bc)/d=(a/d)-(b/d)c\in \Bbb Z.$

(ii).If $d|(a-bc)$ and $d|b$ then $d|a$. Because $(a-bc)/d, b/d\in \Bbb Z$ so $a/d=((a-bc)+bc)/d=(a-bc)/d+(b/d)c\in \Bbb Z.$

With $a=2n-1, b=n, c=2$ we have $\gcd (2n-1,n)=\gcd ((2n-1)-2n, n)=\gcd (-1,n).$ The only divisors of $-1$ are $\pm 1$ and the larger divisor $+1$ divides every $n\in \Bbb Z.$ So $\gcd(-1,n)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

For a), $\gcd(2n-1,n) = \gcd((2n-1-n),n) = \gcd(n-1,n) = 1$ for any consecutive numbers.

For b), $\gcd(4n-2,n) = \gcd(4n-2-3n,n) = \gcd(n-2,n) = \gcd(n,2)$. This could be either $2$ or $1$, depending on the parity of $n$.